# I would create a debug and release version in launch.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, release

I'm looking for a solution to my problem since some weeks.

I code using VScode and the main part of my launch.json file is the following:

```
        ...  
    {
        "name": "Python: Poetry run gui debug",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "python": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/Scripts/python.exe",
        "program": "gui.py",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Poetry run gui release",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "python": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/Scripts/python.exe",
        "program": "gui.py",
        "args": "-O2",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true
    },
    ...
```

But the "optimize" option on the line `"args": "-O2"` isn't recognised. So the program executes always in debug mode. I tried several ways (I didn't want to write all my tries), but the results are the same :(

Does the option apply to my code? Can you help me find an answer please?

Comment: have you put the `args` options in an array: `"args": ["-O2"]`

Comment: Yes, I do. But the same effect. Indeed the variable `__debug__` is always True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-O2` option is the command-line option for the Python interpreter, instead of the arguments for your script.

Unfortunately, VSCode's Python extension doesn't currently support passing options to the Python interpreter in the `launch.json`.

You can create a script to run your `gui.py`:

```
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.run([os.path.join(os.getcwd(), ".venv", "Scripts", "python.exe"), "-O", "gui.py"])
```

Comment: Ok thanks MingJie-MSFT ;( It's sad.
Nevertheless I can run `poetry run python -0 gui.py`
But your idea is nice

Comment: Indeed your script is very good, I just add it to the launch.json : it's a perfect workaround 
Thanks